# if statement on arrays in R

Tags: arrays, r, if-statement

In a simple way of stating my problem, consider I have the following function:

```
> ff<-function(a){ if (a>0){ return ("positive") } else{ return("negative") } }
```

now:

```
> ff(-1)
[1] "negative"
> ff(1)
[1] "positive"
```

while when use an array:

```
> print(ff(c(-1,1)))
[1] "negative" "negative"
Warning message:
In if (a > 0) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I was expecting

```
print(ff(c(-1,1)))=("negative" "positive")
```

How should I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use `symnum` or `cut`. You just have to define the proper cut points.

```
symnum(elements, c(-Inf, 0, Inf), c("negative", "positive"))
negative positive positive negative

cut(elements, c(-Inf, 0, Inf), c("negative", "positive"))
[1] negative positive positive negative
Levels: negative positive
```

Note: Using `elements` vector from oriol-mirosa's answer:

```
elements <- c(-1, 1, 1, -1)
```

---

As an exciting aside, `symnum` will work with matrices as well:

```
# convert elements vector to a matrix
elementsMat <- matrix(elements, 2, 2)
symnum(elementsMat, c(-Inf, 0, Inf), c("negative", "positive"))

[1,] negative positive
[2,] positive negative
```

Answer (score 5):

Your function is not vectorized, so it's not going to work as you expect. You should use `ifelse` instead, which is vectorized:

```
elements <- c(-1, 1, 1, -1)

ff <- function(a) {
  ifelse(a > 0, 'Positive', 'Negative')  
}

ff(elements)

[1] "Negative" "Positive" "Positive" "Negative"
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternately, check out the `dplyr` function for [more reliable behavior](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.1/topics/if_else).

```
a <- c(-1, 1, 1, -1)

if_else(a < 0, "negative", "positive", "missing")
```

which gives:

```
[1] "negative" "positive" "positive" "negative"
```